# Why Does Express Always Return the Local IP Address?

Tags: node.js, express, ip

What I am trying to do is to get the client's IP address. I have attempted two different ways to do so. However, when I send a GET request to the endpoint (root) through Postman, both return ::1, which is the local IP address. With this regard, I am wondering if I could get my own IP address (192.XXX.XXX.XXX) in development. To me, getting back ::1 does not make sense because even though Express is upon running on local, the IP address of the request from Postman should be my own IP Address. Could anyone please explain to me why this happens? If you could also tell me how I can get back my own IP address from Express, that would be appreciated. My code for the implementation is the following:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

//method 1
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.ip;
    //const ip = getIP
    res.status(200).send(ip)
})

//method 2
const getIP = (req)　=> {
    return request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
    ? request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
    : (request.connection && request.connection.remoteAddress)
    ? request.connection.remoteAddress
    : (request.connection.socket && request.connection.socket.remoteAddress)
    ? request.connection.socket.remoteAddress
    : (request.socket && request.socket.remoteAddress)
    ? request.socket.remoteAddress
    : '0.0.0.0';
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost: ${port}`))
```

Comment: When y ou are running locally, the connection will be via localhost, which is 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) or ::1 (IPv6)  Both postman and the server are on the same host, so it will prefer the localhost connection.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So there is no way that I can see if the actual client IP address during development?